# MudBlazor: font-size and spacing in MudSelect and MudList

Tags: list, font-size, spacing, mudblazor

For my purposes, the font size and spacing of the individual items in MudSelect and MudList don't work for me. Unfortunately, my attempts to change these parameters with styles were unsuccessful. That is, the components don't respond to the "font-size:" setting in the style.

```
<MudListItem Style="font-size: 10px">@context.Name</MudListItem>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You will want to start with their [CSS utilities](https://mudblazor.com/utilities/spacing#how-it-works). You can eliminate the padding with:

```cs
<MudListItem Class="pa-0">@context.Name</MudListItem>
```

You generally control font sizes with [the theme](https://mudblazor.com/customization/typography#change-default-font)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<MudListItem Style="--mud-typography-body1-size: 10px;">@context.Name</MudListItem>
```

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cOwQOZnYeaGHumVm